# Receive StackExchange notifications

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, notifications

Is there a way to receive notifications from StackExchange sites in the Notification Center in OSX?

Comment: -1 for posting this in AskDifferent. Would vote you up @meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: why. It's a question about osx.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why MacLemon didn't post [SENotifier](https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x) as a proper answer, but that's your best choice right now. Version 1.1 added the ability to send notifications about your Stack Exchange to Notification Centre.

[image]

> SENotifier is a Mac OS X app that shows the current contents of your
>   Stack Exchange inbox in the menu bar and was inspired by Gmail
>   Notifier.
>
> I created this app so the inbox notifier would be visible all the
>   time, instead of only when a Stack Exchange page was loaded in the
>   browser.
>
> This app uses the new Stack Exchange API v2.0 with authentication, so
>   it can get the current contents of your inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Any app can send notifications in Notification Center, though I'm not sure Stack Exchange has an OS X app to send notifications from, Apple's Mail.app can do it. Go into System Preferences, and to the Notification Center Preference Pane located in the Personal section, and add Mail to the Notification Center. Now, whenever you receive a notification from Stack Exchange via email, you will be notified in Notification Center.